# How to auto update the expired GPG keys of APT?

Tags: apt, package-management, gpg

When you create your own APT repo, you have to create a GPG key for it. 
So you need to import it with:

```
apt-key add yourkey.asc
```

or with a key server:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 3E5C1192
```

However, I do not know any update process for this ? When the key will expire, in both case, do we need to import-it again ?